# How to replace a character in a DB string variable in x86 assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86

Here's my code:

```
TextCol1    DB  0ffh,000h,0ffh,000h,00bh,000h,COL_TEXT_NORM1,COL_BLACK
```

How do I write the code to replace the COL_TEXT_NORM1 with COL_RED_ALERT?

Cheers
Lazy Bones

Comment: What assembler are you programming for?  Something like `mov byte [TextCol1+6], COL_READ_ALERT` should do it modulo some syntax changes.

Comment: - assuming `TextCol1` is in a writable location.

Comment: THANKS FOR REPLYING! I'm using Assembly Language written in 1993. Macro Assembler Version 6.11 (OMG!). Compiles in DOS.

Comment: There's actually no code there.  Suggest to try it in C then translate to assembly once you know how you want to handle the string.  Are you searching for the character, searching for all occurrences, replacing by constant index position, or what.

Answer (score 1):

Program changes value `0bc4:011a = 07h`  to `0bc4:011a = 04h`

```
Before modification:

0BC4:0100  B8 D5 0B 8E D8 BB 04 00-83 C3 06 B0 04 88 07 B8   ................
0BC4:0110  00 4C CD 21 FF 00 FF 00-0B 00 07 00 04 00 47 2E   .L.!..........G.
```

```
After modification:

0BC4:0100  B8 D5 0B 8E D8 BB 04 00-83 C3 06 B0 04 88 07 B8   ................
0BC4:0110  00 4C CD 21 FF 00 FF 00-0B 00 04 00 04 00 47 2E   .L.!..........G.
```

```
.model small
.stack 0ffh
.data
    COL_TEXT_NORM1 equ 07h
    COL_BLACK     equ 00h
    COL_RED_ALERT equ 04h
    TextCol1    DB  0ffh,000h,0ffh,000h,00bh,000h,COL_TEXT_NORM1,COL_BLACK

.code
    start:
        mov ax,@data
        mov ds,ax       
        
        ; fuz's version, indeed better! Instruction is 5 bytes long. 
        mov byte ptr TextCol1+6, COL_RED_ALERT      
        
        ; my version
        ; mov bx, offset TextCol1
        ; add bx,6
        ; mov al, COL_RED_ALERT
        ; mov [bx],al

        mov ax,4c00h
        int 21h
    end start
```

Comment: That is way more complicated than it needs to be.  Just do `mov byte ptr TextCol1+6, COL_RED_ALERT`

Comment: Yeah, why didn't I think of that. :)